# Is there a browser plugin to step into javascript code when an event occurs in the page?

Tags: javascript

So the scenario is: there are a lot of javascript code in a page. If I click a button, it will trigger a certain piece of the code. But I'm not the author of the page so I don't know which file contains that piece nor which function. Is there a way to set such a breakpoint so that I can check the code when it gets executed?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the comments. I found where exactly my problem was. That page calls a method in a library every second so chrome always steps in that method instead of what I really want, which confused me as I thought it wasn't debugging the code correctly. To solve that I asked chrome to ignore the code in that library. That is a experimental feature in chrome for now. This article describes the way to achieve that: http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/ignoring-library-code-while-debugging-in-chrome/

Comment: You can use Chrome's developer tools to do just that: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging?csw=1#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners

Comment: I did a Google search for this question, and I found [several search results that may be useful in this situation](https://www.google.com/#q=step+through+code+browser+javascript).

Comment: @isherwood It isn't clear whether this question is about Google Chrome, though. The question doesn't mention any particular web browser.

Comment: Which makes that a perfect duplicate. As you said, no browser is specified.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are **Event Listener Breakpoints**. In Chrome Developer Tools you can find them on the **Sources** tab.

[Link](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging?csw=1#breakpoints-on-javascript-event-listeners) curtesy of @FelixKling.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is about Google Chrome, though: the question doesn't specify any browser.

Comment: From http://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html#event : Breakpoints on Event Handlers - This feature not yet implemented. Doing development mostly in Chrome i haven't had as much experience with other environments. Feel free to provide a better answer regarding those.